# How to retrieve/access variable from HTML/Javascript in django views to process it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am saving the coordinate (generated by click on `google map`) in the variable `ccc`. Now I want to process this variable in `Django`. How to get its value like we get from HTML input element (for eg. 
`myX = request.POST.get("myInput")`)

Here is the curtailed code:

```
<html>
    <script>
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            var ccc = e.latLng.lat();  //I want to retreive this variable
            //ccc = 77.6746784
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You can send it to your Django server using `XMLHttpRequest` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax request to send data to the server like this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var params = "ccc=" + ccc;
xhr.open("POST", YOUR_DJANGO_VIEW_URL, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the only way to send values from the browser to your django server is to send an HTTP request (using POST because it's submitting data for processing). Whether you use a form and a plain post request (eventually submiting the form via javascript too), or you post using ajax (well, using a XMLHttpRequest object to be exact).